# Stuck Uploading (Google Drive Objective-C API on OS X)

Tags: objective-c, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload simple .txt file as a test. It's only 4kb. Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)uploadFile:(id)sender{

if (![self.credentials canAuthorize]) {
    GTMOAuth2WindowController *windowController;
    windowController = [[[GTMOAuth2WindowController alloc] initWithScope:scope clientID:kClientID clientSecret:kClientSecret keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName resourceBundle:nil] autorelease];
    [windowController signInSheetModalForWindow:self.window
                                       delegate:self
                               finishedSelector:@selector(windowController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

}else{
    NSLog(@"Credentials already authorized.");
}



GTLDriveFile *driveFile = [GTLDriveFile object];
driveFile.title = @"myfile";
driveFile.descriptionProperty = @"Uploaded by Google Drive API test.";
driveFile.mimeType = @"text/plain";

NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:@"/Users/Blake/Downloads/glm/util/autoexp.txt"];




GTLUploadParameters *params = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:driveFile.mimeType];



GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:driveFile uploadParameters:params];

NSLog(@"Starting Upload to Google Drive");

[self.progressBar setHidden:FALSE];
[self.progressBar startAnimation:sender];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *st, GTLDriveFile *df, NSError *error){
    [self.progressBar setHidden:TRUE];
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"File upload succeeded");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Uh-oh: File upload failed");
    }
}];

 }
```

The GTMOAuth2Authentication is authorized and the completion handler block never executes.

I looked at Activity Monitor and it says my application has sent 54 packets in the beginning. So I guess something is being sent.

How can I tell what's going wrong here, if the block never finishes to give me an error?

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently got problem with sticking on GTMOAuth2WindowController. It was unable to present self window. I spent a lot of time in debugger and found that I forget to add WebKit.framework. It was not documented explicitly and there were no any messages in runtime (minus in google dev karma)))). So, maybe your problem also in that? Try to check your frameworks set and compare it with examples shipped with GTL.